# How to open multiple windows of Foxit Reader on macOS?

Tags: macos, pdf, software

I am using Foxit Reader to read PDFs. I am trying to figure out how to open multiple windows simultaneously. For example, in Preview  we can open separate window for every PDF we want to view.

I don't understand the settings as suggested online by Foxit
[image]

Comment: Why can't you just use Preview?  If you're only reading pdf's then Preview should be fine.

Comment: @fsb I need to use foxit, preview is not an option

Comment: Please add your macOS version as well as the Foxit Reader version.

Comment: This is a total hack, but you can probably run in the Terminal: `open -a /Applications/Foxit.app/Contents/MacOS/Foxit` to open a second instance of the app, with a second window. Adjust the path if the application bundle is named something else, I don't actually have Foxit installed!

Comment: Just to close the loop on the PDF/A settings… This is an [archival suitable PDF format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) (used mostly in legal settings) where things like fonts are embedded and not linked and reader features like viewing annotations.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Foxit for Mac help page](https://help.foxitsoftware.com/manuals/pdf-reader/foxit-reader-for-mac/en-us/3.2.0/View_PDF_Files.html), you can open multiple instances.

> Read PDF Files in Multiple Instances
>
> ---
>
> By default, Foxit Reader displays multiple PDF files in different tabs in a single instance. However, you can enable multiple
> instances mode to view PDF files in multiple instances when
> double-click to open PDF files, which is ideal for reading PDF side by
> side.
>
> To enable multiple instances mode, go to `Foxit Reader > Preferences > Documents`, check the `Allow multiple instances` option in **Open
> Setting** group, and click `OK` to apply the setting.
>
> While in multiple instances mode, you can revert to single instance
> mode by redoing the steps and unchecking the Allow multiple instances
> option.

Comment: Please see my post, I added a picture. I don't get these settings in my preferences

Comment: @SoLo I have version 4.1.0 of Foxit Reader, and I have that preference. Maybe check for updates or re-download the software?